# Can you suggest some good optimization books?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, book-recommendation

I am looking for optimization books. Can you suggest some good materials?

First, I started with *Convex Optimization* by Stephen Boyd & Lieven Vandenberghe, but I don't like it because they don't give examples of proofs and techniques, only theory and talking. I need some classical books, for example I like books such as: Zorich, Kreyszig, Kolmogorov and Fomin. Please suggest books that have a similar style. Especially I need books to pursue research in Reinforcement Learning.

Comment: Optimisation is a pretty wide area, if you are more specific you might get better answers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "only theory" because Boyd and Vandenberghe is filled with applications.

Comment: You might be interested in reading Reinforcement Learning and Optimal Control by Bertsekas:https://www.amazon.com/Reinforcement-Learning-Optimal-Control-Bertsekas/dp/1886529396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these books $(1)$ N. S. Kambo, Mathematical Programming Techniques, East West Press, 1997 and
$(2)$ E.K.P. Chong and S.H. Zak, An Introduction to Optimization, 2nd Ed., Wiley, 2010.

Comment: thanks, i started (2), and really loved it.I am also interested in solving problems, but i don't have solutions for those problems.Do you know any source that provides solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Since you've mentioned you wish to take up research in reinforcement learning, I'm assuming by "optimization" you mean both convex and non-convex optimization. I'd suggest you the following depending on your level of understanding:

**1) Introduction to Linear Optimization** by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis: A good starting book on linear optimization that will prepare you for convex optimization.

**2) Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization** by Yurii Nesterov: Nesterov is a living legend in the field of convex optimization. You might have heard his name from the famous `Nesterov Momentum` technique. Be warned, this book isn't light in its usage of mathematics. An even math-heavier version of this book titled **Lectures on Convex Optimization** is also published by Springer.

**3) Optimization for Machine Learning** by Sra, Nowozin and Wright: While I haven't taken a look at this book, I'm told it is high quality and covers both convex and non-convex optimization.

**4) Non-Convex Optimization for Machine Learning** by Jain and Kar: This monograph is a big gun, when it comes to non-convex optimization, and is freely available online. I'm not sure how much of the material would be helpful to you, but it should serve as a good reference. There are not many books which specifically cater to non-convex optimization, this book is one of the first dedicated texts I could find. But then again, this isn't exactly an easy read.

Happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

Optimization by Vector Space Methods by Luenbeger, and Non-Linear Programming by Bertsekas.

Comment: I was curious... Is this one by Luenbeger still relevant? How does it compare to his newer one "Linear and Nonlinear Programming"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Belegundu and Chandrupatla, *Optimization Concepts and Applications in Engineering*.